# Deleting old database and replace it with new database

Tags: android, ddms

I was using a database in my app. Now i have the same database but with few more data in it. I have deleted the old database and pasted the new database to the assets folder. Problem is that the app still shows the data which was in the old database. Now i tried emptying the assets folder and tried running the app and the app dint show errors but showed contents from old database. Which means it is stored. Now i want to remove or delete this old database which is copied to the default location and replace it with the new database. How can i do this? 
NOTE: The old and new database have same database, table and column names.

Comment: Please goto to setting->Apps Manager and Select app then clear data

Comment: Whenever you change the schema of the database or simply in case you want to change the data, you can increment the database version (e.g. If you were using 1, you can make it 2) and everything will be recreated. Hope this helps.

Comment: Or in your app run `Context.deleteDatabase` first to delete the old one. You can also give the database a new version in the dbopenhelper and drop/create all tables.

Comment: @srfarzad: where can i find the setting?

Comment: i am using a database created using sqlitebrowser. am not sure if i can mention versions to it.

Comment: its copy to /data/data/packagename/database

Comment: @user2648852  have u achieve ur task i m facing difficulty in it can u please help me

Comment: @Erum u can uninstall the app from the emulator and re-run the app after replacing ur old database with the new database in the assets folder.

Comment: @user2648852  i want to give apk to the user and user is upgrading database everytime in assets folder .....while database file name is same only version is varying how can i delete old database from real device folder and insert new one i dnt want to delete apk from device

Answer (score 0):

Follow This Path...in eclipse...

DDMS--->File Explorer--->data--->data--->Your Packagename--->Database---->Your Databasefile.

just replace this database file to new Database file and build your project....